# How to change a prop value in a generated vue components for single instance or for all instances?

Tags: vue.js, button, components

Trying to create a simple blog style page. Every post has a like button, that increments when clicked. I generate 10 of these components with a v-for loop, taking data from a vuex store. However, I'd like there to be a button on the home page that resets all of the like counters.

By googling I seem to find and get working solutions that do either one or the other, not together. Yet to get anything working at all except singular counters.

How can I add a button that resets all the PostEntity counter props? Or how should I restructure it? I've thought about somehow doing in with states.

This is my post component, that gets looped in the main view .vue object:

```html
<template>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="postheader">
      <img :src="profilePic" alt="profilepic" class="profilepic" />

      <p>{{ postDate }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="postbody">
      <img :src="postImage" />

      <p>{{ postParagraph }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="postfooter">
      <!--<img :src="require('@/assets/' +nation.drapeau)"/> -->
      <img
        :src="require('@/assets/like.png')"
        class="likepilt"
        @click.prevent="increment"
      />
      <p>Number of likes: {{ count }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'PostEntity',
  props: {
    postDate: String,
    postImage: String,
    profilePic: String,
    postParagraph: String
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.count++;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is how I retrieve info from my VueX store:

```js
getters: {
  postListStuff: state => {
    const postListStuff = state.postList.map(post => {
      return {
        id: post.id,
        img: post.img,
        profilepic: post.profilepic,
        date: post.date,
        paragraph: post.paragraph
      };
    });
    return postListStuff;
  }
}
```

This is how I display the components and generate the posts:

```html
<template>
  <HeaderBox title-text="Homepage" />
  <div v-for="post in postListStuff" :key="post.id" class="posts">
    <PostEntity
      :post-date="post.date"
      :profile-pic="post.profilepic"
      :post-image="post.img"
      :post-paragraph="post.paragraph"
    ></PostEntity>
  </div>
  <FooterBox />
  <HelloWorld />
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';
import HeaderBox from '@/components/Header';
import FooterBox from '@/components/Footer';
import PostEntity from '@/components/Post';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    FooterBox,
    HeaderBox,
    HelloWorld,
    PostEntity
  },
  computed: {
    postListStuff() {
      return this.$store.getters.postListStuff;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible ways to go about doing this, but the simplest way I can think of with least amount of code would be:

Add a `reset` method to the PostEntity component that sets count to 0.

```js
methods: {
  increment() {
    this.count++;
  },
  reset() {
    this.count = 0;
  }
}
```

Then in the parent component add a [ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) to the PostEntity components inside the v-for loop, then add a new button with onclick method `resetCounters`:

```html
<div v-for="post in postListStuff" :key="post.id" class="posts">
  <PostEntity
    ref="post"
    :post-date="post.date"
    :profile-pic="post.profilepic"
    :post-image="post.img"
    :post-paragraph="post.paragraph"
  ></PostEntity>
</div>
<button @click="resetCounters">Reset</button>
```

`resetCounters` will loop through the array of PostEntity refs and call the `reset` method on each of them.

```js
methods: {
  resetCounters() {
    this.$refs.post.forEach(p => p.reset());
  }
}
```